# If statements that use the scrollTop function to change the color of navigation div items at various heights not firing

Tags: jquery

I have a list called `#navigation`. I am trying to at various sections on the page change the color of the list items in the `nav` pane so that the `nav` dot for each individual section is orange and the others are white.
Each `navdot` is given an id of `#dot*` where the asterisk is the number.
The page it self is a single page where the navigation scrolls the user down to a specific section of the page. The list for the navigation is given the id of #navigation. Basically, I am trying to use a scroll function to check the `scrollTop` and if it meets certain parameters, those being that the top slide is the first of a certain section. I want to then use that height information to change that list items color until it gets to a new section.

```
    // JavaScript Document
$( document ).ready(function() {

$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
       $("#navigation>li").css("color","#FFFFFF");
       $("#dot1").css("color","#D96C29");
   }
      if($(window).scrollTop() == $("#slide1").height()) {
       $("#navigation>li").css("color","#FFFFFF");
       $("#dot2").css("color","#D96C29");
   }

      if($(window).scrollTop() == $("#slide1").height() + $("#slide2").height()) {
       $("#navigation>li").css("color","#FFFFFF");
       $("#dot3").css("color","#D96C29");
   }
      if($(window).scrollTop() == $("#slide1").height() + $("#slide2").height() + $("#slide3").height()) {
       $("#navigation>li").css("color","#FFFFFF");
       $("#dot4").css("color","#D96C29");
   }
      if($(window).scrollTop() == $("#slide1").height() + $("#slide2").height() + $("#slide3").height() + $("#slide4").height() + $("#slide5").height()) {
       $("#navigation>li").css("color","#FFFFFF");
       $("#dot5").css("color","#D96C29");
   }
      if($(window).scrollTop() == $("#slide1").height() + $("#slide2").height() + $("#slide3").height() + $("#slide4").height() + $("#slide5").height() + $("#slide6").height() + $("#slide7").height()) {
       $("#navigation>li").css("color","#FFFFFF");
       $("#dot6").css("color","#D96C29");
   }
      if($(window).scrollTop() == $("#slide1").height() + $("#slide2").height() + $("#slide3").height() + $("#slide4").height() + $("#slide5").height() + $("#slide6").height()  + $("#slide7").height() + $("#slide8").height() + $("#slide9").height()) {
       $("#navigation>li").css("color","#FFFFFF");
       $("#dot7").css("color","#D96C29");
   }
      if($(window).scrollTop()  == $("#slide1").height() + $("#slide2").height() + $("#slide3").height() + $("#slide4").height() + $("#slide5").height() + $("#slide6").height()  + $("#slide7").height() + $("#slide8").height() + $("#slide9").height() + $("#slide10").height()  + $("#slide11").height()) {
       $("#navigation>li").css("color","#FFFFFF");
       $("#dot8").css("color","#D96C29");
   }
      if($(window).scrollTop() == $("#slide1").height() + $("#slide2").height() + $("#slide3").height() + $("#slide4").height() + $("#slide5").height() + $("#slide6").height()  + $("#slide7").height() + $("#slide8").height() + $("#slide9").height() + $("#slide10").height()  + $("#slide11").height() + $("#slide12").height() + $("#slide13").height()) {
       $("#navigation>li").css("color","#FFFFFF");
       $("#dot9").css("color","#D96C29");
   }
      if($(window).scrollTop()  == $("#slide1").height() + $("#slide2").height() + $("#slide3").height() + $("#slide4").height() + $("#slide5").height() + $("#slide6").height()  + $("#slide7").height() + $("#slide8").height() + $("#slide9").height() + $("#slide10").height()  + $("#slide11").height() + $("#slide12").height() + $("#slide13").height() + $("#slide14").height() + $("#slide15").height() ) {
       $("#navigation>li").css("color","#FFFFFF");
       $("#dot10").css("color","#D96C29");
   }
      if($(window).scrollTop() == $("#slide1").height() + $("#slide2").height() + $("#slide3").height() + $("#slide4").height() + $("#slide5").height() + $("#slide6").height()  + $("#slide7").height() + $("#slide8").height() + $("#slide9").height() + $("#slide10").height()  + $("#slide11").height() + $("#slide12").height() + $("#slide13").height() + $("#slide14").height() + $("#slide15").height() + $("#slide16").height() + $("#slide17").height()) {
       $("#navigation>li").css("color","#FFFFFF");
       $("#dot11").css("color","#D96C29");
   }
      if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       $("#navigation>li").css("color","#FFFFFF");
       $("#dot12").css("color","#D96C29");
   }
   });
});
```

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle with your html?

Comment: That would be difficult, there's a lot of employer specific links up in it. I'll try to cut all of that out though and set one up.

Comment: instead of using `==` for comparison, you should probably use `<=` or `>=`. There is no guarantee that the `scrollTop()` will match exactly.

Comment: @BrianGlaz Hey the >= operator did the trick if you want to throw that in an answer I can select it. Didn't realize how literal the operators were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using `==` for comparison, you use `<=` or `>=`. There is no guarantee that the `scrollTop()` value will match exactly with combined height of the DOM elements.